# Adding information to Notification Centre

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm currently creating an app and I want some information to show in the menu that is shown when you slide down from the top. I want it to look like the image below does for VPN Proxy Master, but the information displayed is different of course.

[image]

Can anyone give me some advice as to what I should research into so that I can make this possible? I'm not too sure on the naming schemes of things.

Comment: In Android app development, those are called [notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications).

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm looking for something that will allow me to have the same scenario while the app is still running. Whats the specific area in notifications that I should look for?

Comment: Um, that's still a `Notification`. Your app will be running when you display the `Notification`, by definition (otherwise your code to display it would not be running). Whether your app is running afterwards will depend on a range of factors. A foreground service is a typical scenario for having a `Notification` while doing work in the background.